# Very basic questions about Ursina Engine

Tags: ursina

I'm a beginner with the Ursina Engine.

It seems to be a pretty good API, and I'm eager to learn more about it. However, I'm looking to understand some basic aspects of the Ursina Engine:

1. Is there any way to display the window like a normal desktop application? By default, the Ursina Engine shows a window without a top bar, having only a close button, so I can't move the window around.
2. Is there an official way to package the application? I'm wondering if there's a method to package my game once I've finished developing it. Do I need to use a Python packaging tool like PyInstaller or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there any way to display the window like a normal desktop application? By default, the Ursina Engine shows a window without a top bar, having only a close button, so I can't move the window around.

Yes, you can add `borderless=False` flag on app init:

```
app = ursina.Ursina(borderless=False)
```

[image: ursina]

> 2. Is there an official way to package the application? I'm wondering if there's a method to package my game once I've finished developing
>    it. Do I need to use a Python packaging tool like PyInstaller or
>    something similar?

Yes, there is an official way:

```
python -m ursina.build
```

For more details see here: https://www.ursinaengine.org/building.html